# MADLIB installation fails on WSL - Ubuntu with cannot open `SQLCommon.m4'

Tags: cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux, plpython, madlib, postgres-plpython

I am trying to install madlib on my wsl - ubuntu.
I have installed the following -
Postgres-14.10 --with-python enabled.
cmake - 3.22.1
m4 (GNU M4) - 1.4.18
madlib - 2.1.0 gz file from [the link](https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/madlib/2.1.0/apache-madlib-2.1.0-src.tar.gz)

Then followed [the official guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MADLIB/Installation+Guide#InstallationGuide-CompileFromSourceCompilingFromSource)

when I run

```
$BUILD_ROOT/src/bin/madpack -s madlib -p postgres -c [user[/password]@][host][:port][/database] install
```

I get this error -

[SQLCOMMON.M4 error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVfTr.png)

However upon looking up in the directory, I can see the SQLCOMMON.m4_in file is present -
[M4_in present image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUtco.png)

I am not sure where does the installation go wrong.
Has anyone managed to setup madlib on ubuntu lately? If yes, how?????????

So far I have tried setting up on 2 different Ubuntus on wsl - Ubuntu, and Ubuntu-22.04.
Also tried to install using numerous combinations of pgxnclient, postgres, python versions, cmake versions, m4 versions, from source.
Closest I got was from pgxnclient.
But when I tried creating the extension with

```
CREATE EXTENSION MADLIB;
```

I get the error - extension PLPYTHONU not available.
Only available is PLPYTHON3U.